# Word for someone has changed his name?

Tags: word-request

If someone, previously named John Smith, now changed to Mohammed bin Usman, is there a word to describe such a person?

Comment: Your question is not clear. His new name would be considered a "legal name change", but that alone doesn't change a person. It seems like you are asking what else changed, but we don't know the person at all.

Comment: @user3169 in which part of the question have you got the impression that something else except the name also changed?

Comment: @user3169 I think he wants to know what "someone who changed his/her name" is called. Like, someone who killed is called a killer. I don't think there's such a word in English.

Comment: I know what you are asking. But you can't "describe" a person using their name, other than to say it changed (which you already stated). So what are you looking for?

Comment: @user3169 of course we can describe a person by something he did, as Albert said, someone killed can be called a killer, someone who won a tournament can be called a champion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an actual noun for such a thing. The only way I can think of to describe these people is to use a verbal phrase:

> Would all of the people *who have been* ***renamed*** please move to the other side of the room.

From Merriam-Webster's definition of [*rename*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rename):

> : to give (someone or something) a new name
>   // *renamed* the street in honor of the late mayor
>   //  . . . a 16-year-old who left the Orthodox life a year ago. He has *renamed* himself Adam to cement the break . . .
>   — Ron Kampeas
>   // The program was actually a relatively simple . . . script that *renames* files on your hard drive . . .
>   — Michael J. Miller

You could coin a new term such as *new-names*, and it might even be understood, but it would certainly not be in common (or even uncommon) use.